# Session error :Object not set to an instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asyncfileupload

In my webpage I'm not able to get the session variable on post back in remote server.

The problem is

if the page is not IsPostback then I'm able to get the session variable.

But if the page postback then the error appears.

This same error comes when i use the asynchfile upload. I'm using asynchfileupload to upload a image and store it to a session variable. and later on button click i am saving data to directory.

this problem arouse when i upload any files to the server.i am using the asynchfileupload control to upload the image.,but it is not occuring frequently.

here is my code

```
protected void AsynImageLoader_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (AsynImageLoader.PostedFile != null)
    {
        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AsynImageLoader.PostedFile.FileName);

        if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".gif" || extension == ".jpeg" || extension == ".png")
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = AsynImageLoader.PostedFile;
            Session["TempImage"] = ReadFile(file);
        }
    }
}
```

on button click

```
   var storedImage = Session["TempImage"] as byte[];
   String Strthumbpath = Server.MapPath("content\\thumbnail\\");
   if (storedImage != null)
   {
       System.Drawing.Image image = GetImage(storedImage);
       if (image != null)
       {
       image.Save(Strthumbpath + strFileName);
       }

       }
```

inserting values to datbase.

after somuch googling i read that when any files is adding to any sub directory or editing the webconfig will cause cause the application to restart.

if so how can i solve this..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try passing it as hidden form value instead of session - any luck?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your session variable called "User_id" is getting removed when you post back. You're seeing "Object not set to an instance of an object" because you're trying to perform the "ToString()" method on a null object, which isn't allowed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes you are right.here i am confused why the session variable user_id is becoming null on post back and page refresh.but on the poage load if not ispostback then i am getting session value.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide code, without that we can't guess the issue.
Though, you can always do null checking on your session variable before using it.

```
if(Session["User_id"]) != null;
```

Comment: i have updated my question with code.can u check it.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check you sesssion if its null or empty as follows:

```
 if (Session["User_id"] == null || Session["User_id"].ToString() == string.Empty)
 {
    Response.write(Session["User_id"].ToString());
 }
 else
 {
   // your code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `web.config` file on your remote machine and ensure that the [`sessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) element is configured correctly. You might have the `mode` attribute set to `Off` on your remote server.

As others have pointed out you could code more defensively checking for `null` before accessing properties on the object you've got stored in session.

Comment: in my webconfig file the session is given as <sessionState mode="InProc"></sessionState>

Comment: Can you check whether you can create a cookie on page load when you're not doing a postback then try and read the cookie value when the page is posted back? I think there might be problem storing and retrieving the session cookie used by ASP.NET. Does the hostname in your URL contain the underscore character ('_') by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

First check session.

```
if (Session["User_id"] == null)
{
//Put code here

}
else
{
     Response.Write(Session["User_id"]);

     // or you can write as below

     Response.Write(Convert.ToString(Session["User_id"]));
}
```

Never use `.ToString()` Method, you should use `Convert.ToString`, this is handle null value also.

Comment: my doubt is why the session variable is becoming null on page postback and page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The button click event happens **AFTER** the page Load event... this might be why it's not set. ;-)